# Handle CLOB columns with PHP-ODBC

Tags: php, oracle, odbc

I maintain a legacy application that runs on PHP/5.2.6 under Windows Server 2003 and connects to a remote Oracle 10g server through ODBC. I'm writing a new feature that needs a CLOB column so it can store arbitrarily large texts but I can't find the way to manipulate it via good old ODBC functions.

For writing, I've tried this approach:

```
<?php

$sql = 'INSERT INTO FOO (FOO_ID, FOO_CLOB) VALUES (?, ?)';
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
$res = odbc_execute($stmt, array(1, 'Very large string'));

?>
```

But as soon as the string is larger than 4,000 bytes:

> SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC driver for
>   Oracle]Error en el parámetro 2: Datos
>   truncados, SQL state 01004 in
>   SQLExecute

... which roughly means "Truncated data". I have a similar problem when reading: it works fine until I receive more than 4,000 bytes.

Is it possible to manipulate a CLOB column with more than 4,000 bytes using PHP ODBC functions?

*(My alternative is to store stuff in files and only save the file path on DB but I'd like to avoid that if possible.)*

---

**Update:** Following [Justin Cave's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549196/handle-clob-columns-with-php-odbc/5549394#5549394), I've dumped Microsoft's ODBC Driver in favour of Oracle's and my code inserts large strings without changes. My question now is how to read the CLOB column. Reading it as-is:

```
$sql = 'SELECT FOO_ID, FOO_CLOB FROM FOO';
$res = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)){
    // ...
}
```

... triggers this when running `odbc_fetch_array()`:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match
>   format string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have to use the Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle?  That driver [does not support the CLOB data type](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244661) among various other issues.  If you use the Oracle ODBC driver instead, the driver will support CLOBs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, that fixed the INSERT problem. Now I need advice for the SELECT part `<:-)`

Answer (score 1):

In order to read you , basically, have to chunk you way through the data.

Something like --

```
define ("MAX_LONGREAD_LENGTH", 4000);

$res = odbc_exec($con, $sql);

odbc_binmode($res, ODBC_BINMODE_RETURN);

$oflen = odbc_field_len($res, 1);

if ( $oflen >= MAX_LONGREAD_LENGTH)
{
  $out = '';

  do
  {
    $temp = odbc_result($res, 1);

    if ($temp != null) $out .= $temp;
  }

  while ($temp != null);
}

else

{
  $out = odbc_result($res, 1);
}
```

-- which, basically, either -

1. Reads all the data if <6000 chars, or
2. Repeatedly, reads and appends chunks of data until no more is returned.

Comment: Thank you very much! `odbc_binmode()` prevents the error when fetching the row and `odbc_result($res, FOO_CLOB)` allows to read the remaining chunks. I wish I could tag two answers as accepted.